# My rails -v differs from my gem list rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on ubuntu, and I'm not as adept in it as Windows, and I'm trying to install rails.
I tried one installation and got Rails 2.3.14, when I wanted 4.0.0. I then found what I think to be the correct installation via sudo gem install rails, and I got 4.0.0. However, I can't seem to use the rails 4.0.0 version. When I'm in terminal and run the rails -v command, I get rails 2.3.14.

However, in my 'gem list', I see rails 4.0.0, but not rails 2.3.14... I'm not sure where rails 2.3.14 is... how would I get rid of it and/or get ruby to use rails 4.0.0?

Comment: List the various commands you have typed. What did you do to make this possible? :  *....I tried one installation and got Rails 2.3.14, when I wanted 4.0.0 ...*

Comment: I was browsing some how-to-get-rails guides, and one had some long terminal download that I don't quite remember and that one gave me 2.3.14 and that seems to be the one that I am pointing to if I type in 'rails' in terminal. I got 4.0.0 through 'gem install rails', which I think was the proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided that my system was too messed up and started from the ground up starting from the ground up.

I used this blog as a guide and it worked: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are installing the Ubuntu Ruby/Rails etc. In order to have multiple Ruby and Rails with different Gem versions, you should use [RVM](https://rvm.io). You can then switch back and forth between different versions of everything on a project base. I find the Ubuntu packages always being a little behind of what the Rails community is used to.

Comment: I do have RVM, it's very useful. However, it's the rails versioning that was messing me up, not my ruby

Comment: With RVM you manage the Ruby version **and** all the Gems. Rails is a Gem.

Answer (score 0):

Install bundler.

`gem install bundler`

Then in your rails app gemfile, list the rails version you need to use.

`gem :rails '4.0.x'`

Ensure your ruby is modern

`ruby --version`

If it is not, find a tutorial on `rbenv` or `rvm`.

(Rbencv will let you avoid using dangerous Sudo commands that you do not yet know the scope of.  )

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

```
gem cleanup
```

It clears the older version of gems if newer version is present.